# How can I do a bar chart (histogram) to categories with big names in R?

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart

I want to do the following bar chart in R:
[image]

I have the following code:

```html
antropico <- c(4,111,40,19,345,13,487,4,450,445,13,15)

barplot(antropico,
        xlab = "Frecuencia de ocurrencia",
        ylab = "Factor antrópico",
        names.arg = c("Accidente Industrial", "Accidente materiales riesgosos", "Accidente recreacional", "Accidente simple", "Accidente transporte", "Alteración de infraestructura", "Alteración suministro servicio báisco", "Explosión", "Incendio estructural", "Incendio Forestal", "Incendio transporte", "Incendio vertedero\relleno sanitario"),
        col = "blue",
        horiz = TRUE)
```

But the thing is that the names are too large, and R gives me a warning: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large. I am also having problems to plot the numbers over the bars, any idea?. Thanks in advance.

PD: Everything must be in Spanish, so if somebody has a solution that won't work if the labels of categories are in Spanish language, so thanks, but this language is obligatory to me.

Comment: Are you interested in a `ggplot2` solution ?

Comment: Of course, if it can be a with the labels in Spanish I would take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
# put all in a dataframe
ant_df <- data.frame(names= c("Accidente Industrial", "Accidente materiales riesgosos", "Accidente recreacional", "Accidente simple", "Accidente transporte", "Alteración de infraestructura", "Alteración suministro servicio báisco", "Explosión", "Incendio estructural", "Incendio Forestal", "Incendio transporte", "Incendio vertedero\relleno sanitario"),
                 values=c(4,111,40,19,345,13,487,4,450,445,13,15))

ggplot(ant_df,aes(x=names,y=values)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="blue") +  # add bars
    coord_flip() + # flip x and y axis
    ylab("Frecuencia de ocurrencia") + xlab("Factor antrópico") + # add axis labels
     geom_text(aes(x = names,   y = values+30, label = values)) # add text labels
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Excellent, it fixes my problem 100%, thanks and greetings from Chile.

Comment: If you would like the names in order from the top, rather than the bottom, change `ggplot()` to read `ggplot(ant_df, aes(fct_rev(names), values))`. If you'd like the bars ordered by size, try `ggplot(ant_df, aes(fct_reorder(names, values), values))`. And if you like less typing try `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat="identity")`.